# Coordinate functions on the box topology are not necessarily continuous?

Tags: general-topology

For an exercise, we have to prove that the product topology is the finest topology such that for any continuous map $f : X \to \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$, the coordinate functions $f_{\alpha} := \pi_{\alpha} f$ are continuous as well.

Argument for why this is true in the product topology: start with an open $U_{\alpha} \subset X_{\alpha}$, then $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is the product of $U_{\alpha}$ with $\prod_{\beta \in J \setminus {\alpha}} X_{\beta}$ which is open, and hence $f^{-1}(\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_{\alpha}))$ is open as well by continuity of $f$.

I don't see why this fails in the box topology, which is a finer topology than the product topology (unless almost all of the $X_{\alpha}$s have the trivial topology). The argument seems like it would hold since the preimage of $\pi_{\alpha}$ on an open set $U_{\alpha}$ is still open in the box topology. In fact, my intuition would say that the product topology is in actually the coarsest topology that makes this true: any finer topology contains the product topology, so the argument will hold.

Comment: It's a good exercise to prove the product topology $\mathscr{G}$ is unique—unique in that it is the only topology on $X=\prod X_n$ such that for each topological space $W$ and each map $f\colon W\to X$, $f$ is continuous iff each $\pi_i\circ f$ is continuous. I think that will illustrate why the box topology fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; the statement you are trying to prove is wrong.  Instead, as you guessed, the product topology is actually the *coarsest* topology with the property you described.  Alternatively, the product topology is the finest topology such that given any map $f:X\to\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$ such that $\pi_\alpha f$ is continuous for all $\alpha$, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll have to clarify with the professor which version is meant then :)